# Python invert colors

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I need to invert the colors of an image in Python using PIL, the problem is that I only have to invert the colors of the right half of the image and I don't know how to do it. [image] Here is an example of how the image should look like.

And here is the code I made, bot it invert the colors of all the image.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL.ImageOps

image_file = Image.open("Abbildung1.jpg")
image_file.load()
image_data = np.asarray(image_file, dtype=np.uint8)

inverted_image = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image_file)

inverted_image.save("neuesBild.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy` to make two parts of the image then apply the transformation and finally combine it.

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL.ImageOps

image_file = Image.open("some_image.jpeg")
image_file.load()
image_data = np.asarray(image_file, dtype=np.uint8)
width = image_data.shape[1]

left_half = image_data[:,0:width//2, :]
right_half = image_data[:,width//2:, :]

inverted_image_right = np.asarray(PIL.ImageOps.invert(Image.fromarray(right_half)))

total_image = np.hstack((left_half, inverted_image_right))

inverted_image = Image.fromarray(total_image)


inverted_image.save("invertion_half.jpeg")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it:

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps

img = Image.open('img.png').convert('RGB')
img.paste(ImageOps.invert(img.crop((img.width/2,0,img.width,img.height))),box=(int(img.width/2),0))
```

We have croped, inverted and pasted this croped-inverted image back.

Then you can check:

```
img.show()
```